# How to display a dynamically generated full html page from within an angular single page app?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular js app.  One of the things it does is call a service that returns a string with a full html page. Not a fragement. So the following string is available within angular app:

```
  <html> Some content </html>
```

How can it redirect the user to a page or view that will display the full html page?

Note, its not a fragment, and not practical to slice it up and put as subview in angular that can be snapped in. Hence the question.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to render a full page that includes css and scripts? Objective/problem isn't entirely clear

Comment: Do you want the whole page to be replaced by the new string (html)?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an iframe:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{iframeUrl}}"></iframe>
```

Comment: can iframeurl be a string of content?  In this case the html is not hosted somewhere but the full html content is available as a string ....

Comment: Yeah if its not dynamic then I would just do  <iframe src="static/source.html"></iframe>

Comment: Its dynamicly generated so what is have is <html> dynamic content <html>  where header everything is dynamically generated.  So I have everything but its a string not a hosted html page somewhere.

Comment: then try <iframe>{{myHtmlThatsTooCoolToBeonAServer}}</iframe>.  That's all I got for you.  Don't understand enough of the use case but it sounded like an iframe when you said full html.  Good luck!

Comment: Last comment makes no sense. The only time anything inside `<iframe>` tag gets rendered is when browser doesn't support iframes